# Regular expression to match meta tags

Tags: php, regex, meta-tags

Hi I want to extract the og:image content from a page source. How can I extract og:image meta tag content from source?

This is meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.moneycontrol.com/news_image_files/2013/s/Syrian_diesel_trucks_190.jpg" />
```

How can I identify the meta tag using regular expression?

This is my current function grab image url from img tags. What modification it needed to work with og:image meta tags?

```
function feeds_imagegrabber_scrape_images($content, $base_url, array $options = array(), &$error_log = array()) {

// Merge the default options.
$options += array(
  'expression' => '//img',
  'getsize' => TRUE,
  'max_imagesize' => 512000,
  'timeout' => 10,
  'max_redirects' => 3,
  'feeling_lucky' => 0,
);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
if (@$doc->loadXML($content) === FALSE && @$doc->loadHTML($content) === FALSE) {
  $error_log['code'] = -5;
  $error_log['error'] = "unable to parse the xml//html content";
  return FALSE;
}

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$hrefs = @$xpath->evaluate($options['expression']);//echo '<pre> HREFS : ';print_r($hrefs->length);exit;

if ($options['getsize']) {
  timer_start(__FUNCTION__);
}

$images = array();
$imagesize = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
  $url = $hrefs->item($i)->getAttribute('src');
  if (!isset($url) || empty($url) || $url == '') {
    continue;
  }
  if(function_exists('encode_url')) {
    $url = encode_url($url);
  }
  $url = url_to_absolute($base_url, $url);

  if ($url == FALSE) {
    continue;
  }

  if ($options['getsize']) {
    if (($imagesize = feeds_imagegrabber_validate_download_size($url, $options['max_imagesize'], ($options['timeout'] - timer_read(__FUNCTION__) / 1000))) != -1)   {
      $images[$url] = $imagesize;
      if ($settings['feeling_lucky']) {
        break;
      }
    }
    if (($options['timeout'] - timer_read(__FUNCTION__) / 1000) <= 0) {
      $error_log['code'] = FIG_HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT;
      $error_log['error'] = "timeout occured while scraping the content";
      break;
    }
  }
  else {
    $images[$url] = $imagesize;
    if ($settings['feeling_lucky']) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($images);exit;
return $images;
}
```

Comment: You can always create a complex regex to parse HTML or you can use php  [DomDocument](http://us3.php.net/domdocument)

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: XPath: `//meta[@property='og:image']`, seem a lot more handy then regexes.

Comment: @Wrikken I want something like that. I tried your solution, it is not working. I have updated the question with my current function. Please check.

Comment: i have a doubt. meta tags are coming inside `head` tag. any issue for that?

Comment: I normally have 0 problems with those, they're not special, neither is the `head` from a `DOM` perspective. Could you post a minimal testcase (so exact input, your attempt at capturing that meta tag, and your output) on something like codepad.org, so we can see exactly what is going on / what might be some quirks in the input etc.?

Comment: My assumption was correct. My html grabber function was only taking content inside body tag. That is why it was not working. Now everything is fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

If you must use regex, this would work:

```
<meta.*property="og:image".*content="(.*)".*\/>
```

Regex example: http://regex101.com/r/rX1zK7

PHP example

```
$html = '<html>
           <head>
             <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.moneycontrol.com/news_image_files/2013/s/Syrian_diesel_trucks_190.jpg" />
           </head>
           <body>
           </body>
         </html>';

preg_match_all('/<meta.*property="og:image".*content="(.*)".*\/>/', $html, $matches);

echo $matches[1][0];
```

Output:

```
http://www.moneycontrol.com/news_image_files/2013/s/Syrian_diesel_trucks_190.jpg
```

Comment: This won't work, if property isn't enclosed by double quotes e.g `property=og:image`

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `DOMDocument` Class

```
<?php
$html='<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.moneycontrol.com/news_image_files/2013/s/Syrian_diesel_trucks_190.jpg" />';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $tag) {
    if ($tag->getAttribute('property') === 'og:image') {
        echo $tag->getAttribute('content');
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
http://www.moneycontrol.com/news_image_files/2013/s/Syrian_diesel_trucks_190.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(<meta[^>]*>)
```

what means:
select `<meta`
... everything but not ">" zero or more times
and at the end >

it works with:

```
<meta .... >
```

and

```
<meta ..../>
```